# Azure DevOps Services ServerGate task questions

Tags: azure-devops

I am creating a custom ServerGate task and had two questions.

1. Can ServerGate task be run on self-hosted agent instead of running Agentless? I did some research and many people have told that is can only run Agentless..
2. If it can only be run on Agentless, I am wondering if it's possible to run the Invoke-RestAPI task to hit my generic service connection (internal address)? seems like it can't from the log

Cannot get DNS address for host "https:\internaladdress.coom

Update ** 12/15
I'm trying to run Invoke REST API:GET here to evaluate something, looks like it's only running agentless so it is not able to connect to our internal server?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you run a task in an agent job, there should be a tool or application has been installed on the agent machine that can be used to parse, compile or execute the code of the task.

For example, when you want to execute Invoke-RestAPI in agent job, you generally need to use the PowerShell (or other suitable shells) installed on the agent machine to execute the API.

If you do not want to use the 3rd-party tools to execute your task, you may need to develop a tool by yourself to parse, compile and execute your task.

**[UPDATE]**

In your case, using a Generic service connection to run the Invoke REST API task does not work. It can't connect to your internal server.

As a workaround, you can try like as the steps below:

- Install a self-hosted agent on your internal server machine (both virtual machine on cloud and physical machine are OK).
- Setup a shell script to execute the API.
- In your pipeline, add a job runs on the self-hosted agent to execute the shell script via a shell script task.

In this way, due to the API is executed directly on your internal server machine, you do not need to setup the additional service connection.

Comment: Hello, I want to the Invoke RestAPI to connect to our internal server

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity, I have updated my above answer. Please check it and have a try. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: hi Bright Ran, I have my self-hosted agent already but can I use it in my GateTask?

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity, It depends on how you design this task to be orchestrated and executed.

As I explained above, if you design that your task will use some tools or applications (e.g. Node, PowerShell, CMD, Bash, etc.) installed on your agent machine to parse, compile and execute the code of the task, yes, it is a task of agent job, you can run it on your self-hosted agent.

If you design that your task is orchestrated by and executed on the server, it is a task of agentless job, you can't run it on your self-hosted agent.

Comment: Hi @wonderfulworldwithcharity, how are things going? Is my above explanation and suggestion helpful to you? If you have any questions about this ticket, feel free to tell me.